# Add space between numbers in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, cell-format

How to I add space automatically to a 22-digit number?

For example:  1234567891234567891234 needs to be formatted
to 123456 7891234567891234 (basically added a space after 6).

Answer (score 1):

Excel only allows up to `15` significant digits so a 22-digit number can only be represented in Excel as a text value, hence you can't use number formatting. To get the required result in another cell you can use `REPLACE` function to add a space at character 7, i.e.

`=REPLACE(A1,7,0," ")`

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Left", "Right" and "Concatenate" Excel string functions.

If A12 = `1234567891234567891234` then use something like:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A12,6) & " " & RIGHT(A12,16))
```

Comment: Using the `CONCATENATE` function is not necessary. This can be shortened to `=LEFT(A12,6)&" "&RIGHT(A12,16)`.

Answer (score 0):

Take note of the first response that stipulated that the cell containing the 22 digit number be formatted as a string (assuming that you are inputing or importing it without the desired space).

If you are importing, I would suggest that you prepend a single-quote character in front of the value imported, to ensure that Excel interprets it as a string. I would also suggest a VBA routine that would change the 'no-space' version into the 'space' version something like this, that you would run on the specified cells after the data has been entered / imported...

```
Sub AddSpace()

Dim cl         As Range

For Each cl In Selection
    If Mid(cl.Value, 6, 1) <> " " Then
        cl.Value = Left(cl.Value, 6) & " " & Right(cl.Value, Len(cl.Value) - 6)
    End If
Next cl
End Sub
```

This tests that you aren't inserting a double-space, and will treat shorter values as well. You could also test for all-numeric values, etc.

Cheers,

Dean

Answer (score -1):

nothing ...after selecting required cells  just press ctrl+F and opt replace option and edit in "find what" as the normal text and numbers and add  in "replace with" in what model you want cintends (ie.text with space) .then press replace all.

Answer (score -1):

Simple formula is 
=TEXT(A1,"0000 0000 0000")

Comment: Actually,  `=TEXT(A1, "0 0000000000000000")` would be a better answer for the question that was asked.